# How to properly display iFrame in Opera Mobile

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I have an iframe on my pages which is properly displayed almost on all browsers. But not in Opera Mobile. How to optimize html code to properly display my iframes on Opera Mobile too?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Opera mobile and tablet seem to render iframes at the full size of their content (which prevents overflow scrolling).  This is similar if not identical to the way iOS 5 handles iframes.  You may need to allow the whole page to scroll rather than relying on the iframe to contain content in the window.